# What issues will arise launching on LAMP from development on XAMPP?

Tags: php, windows, linux, xampp, lamp

I am considering developing a php/MySql website on my Windows machine. But I am worried about complications when I go to put it on the the server at, say, GoDaddy and the issues that may arise from their LAMP (they would use LAMP, right?) stack.

Are they too perilous and/or numerous to rationalize development with the XAMPP (what about WAMP?) stack on Windows? Is developing on a Linux machine the real solution?

-Turo

Answer (score 0):

The most important thing will be difference in handling of paths (windows uses \ for path separator, linux uses /) and filenames (windows is not case sensitive, linux is). Both these can be handled in platform independent manner.

Other than that, if you make sure you have same extensions loaded, you should be fine.

P.S. There's also a set of Windows-only PHP extensions, which for obvious reasons you should avoid if you wan't your application to run on linux.
http://www.php.net/manual/en/refs.utilspec.windows.php